# Active record select query to where and joins query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I currently have the following Active Record `.select` query being utilised in one of my controllers:

```
@bids = current_user.bids.select { |bid| !bid.bid_has_failed_date }
```

and the `bid_has_failed_date` method in my `Bid` model for the condition:

```
def bid_has_failed_date
  self.real_property_sale.try(:real_property_sale_project).try(:failed_date).present?
end
```

I would prefer to use `.where` and `.joins` to do the same thing. So far I've got this:

```
.where(agent_id: agent_id).joins(real_property_sale: :real_property_sale_project).where(real_property_sale_projects: { failed_date: nil })
```

The problem with this is that it will only return a bid that has `real_property_sale_project` and a `failed_date` of nil. Instead I need it to return all bids excluding those where `failed_date` is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where(agent_id: agent_id) - 
  where(agent_id: agent_id)
   .joins(real_property_sale: :real_property_sale_project)
    .where.not(real_property_sale_projects: { failed_date: nil })
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution was very close have made a small amendment. Will mark as correct as it pointed me in the right direction.